# Making client new a member of class

Tags: class, architecture, software-design

I have been using an API to do some work. This is how I used it first time round:

```
var someStuff = new myObject ();
someStuff.Name = "stackOverflow";
someStuff.Options.MaxSurname = 5; //this caused me to get a runtime exception, Options is Null
```

Fix was simple. I obviously had to new the Options member to create an instance.

```
someStuff.Options = new Options ();
someStuff.Options.MaxSurname = 5;
```

This now works as expected, obviously. Is this okay? As a client I was unaware that I had to new this Options member. Quick fix once I went to debug and got a runtime null object exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this okay.
For some reason the API you're using requires you to contruct an Options object, and the compiler cannot check for this (hence the exception at runtime).

You could also contruct the object before applying it to SomeStuff, if this feels more natural to you:

```
Options someOptions = new Options ();
someOptions.MaxSurname = 5;
someStuff.Options = someOptions;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I do it now, to make it feel more natural as you said. I know the compiler is non the wiser in this situation, I was just thinking if there was an alternative way to design such a class. i.e a construct on first use or something similar.

Comment: @Science_Fiction: Sure, the myObject class can construct an Options object on initialization; or it could require an options parameter in the constructor. It all really depends on how much you want to constrain the usage of the API. (Is making an Options object required, for example...)

Comment: Setting up Options is optional. So I guess that's why it is not initialized in the constructor, since it could be deemed pointless as no one goes on to use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use a factory method.

sample code:

```
public class MyObjectFactory
{
    public static MyObject CreateSomeObject()
    {
        return new MyObject() { SomeOptions = new Options(); }
    }
}

// used as ...
var myObject = MyObjectFactory.CreateSomeObject();
myObject.Options.MaxSurNames = 5;
```

hence you can no longer get an incomplete instance of MyObject. AND its feeling natural.